# If I use api.imply in package.js do I have to use api.use for the same package?

Tags: meteor, package

When construction meteor packages you can add files like this:

```
api.use('fourseven:scss@0.9.4', ['client', 'server']);
```

You can also tell meteor to give the package user access to other packages like this:

```
api.imply('fourseven:scss@0.9.4', ['client', 'server']);
```

In the documentation it's not clear if implying a package also makes it available. For instance, I'm not sure if it is redundant to do this:

```
api.use('fourseven:scss@0.9.4', ['client', 'server']);
api.imply('fourseven:scss@0.9.4', ['client', 'server']);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just tested this use case with a couple packages of mine and I can assert that implying a package doesn't make it available automatically in the package source.

So it means that

```
api.use("foo:bar@x.y.z");
api.imply("foo:bar@x.y.z");
```

is NOT redundant if you intend to use and reference `foo:bar` in the current package source.

You can think of `api.imply` as an `api.use` for the app context that has no impact on the current package context.

I've heard that some time in the future they plan to integrate a package-like API for the app context, which is going to be useful to address load order among other things.

Comment: That "package-like API for the app context" is now in Meteor 1.3 (beta at time of writing), and it is NPM packages. You can now `npm install` anything in the app root, and `require()` or `import` (es6) anything into your app code. You'll be able to control load order using this mechanism, via the new `modules` package.