# What does api.imply do?

Tags: meteor

From the [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_api_imply):

> Give users of this package access to another package (by passing in the string `packagename`) or a collection of packages (by passing in an array of strings `[packagename1, packagename2]`).

I have no idea what it means.
From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607825/if-i-use-api-imply-in-package-js-do-i-have-to-use-api-use-for-the-same-package) I know that `imply` can be employed with `use`.

What does `api.imply` do?
What's exactly the difference between `api.use` and `api.imply`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`api.use` gives a package access to other packages exported symbols.

For example you need to `api.use("random")` ([see how it's done in the accounts-base package](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-base/package.js#L11)) if you want to use the `Random` symbol in a package code ([see how the `random` `package.js` is `api.export`ing `Random`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/random/package.js#L8)).

However, `meteor add`ing `accounts-base` wouldn't give your whole application access to its used packages (`random` in this case). If your app needs `random`, you'd still need to `meteor add` it.

---

`api.imply` on the other hand, gives the whole application access to that package exported symbols.

For example, [see how `accounts-google` is `api.imply`ing `accounts-base`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-google/package.js#L10).

[`accounts-base` is responsible for exporting the `Accounts` symbol](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-base/package.js#L36), when you `meteor add accounts-google`, not only does `accounts-base` is also added in your application dependencies, but `accounts-base` symbols are also made available in your app, specifically because it was implied.

---

`accounts-base` is both using `Accounts` in its own code (`api.use`) and exporting its dependencies symbols to the whole app (`api.imply`).

`api.imply` can be used to make "shadow packages" that are just pulling in some other packages.

For example, at some point MDG renamed the `showdown` package to `markdown`, they could just have stated to `meteor remove showdown && meteor add markdown`, but it would have required some actions on end users.

What they did instead is keeping the `showdown` package and just [make it implying the new `markdown` package](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/21bdac87347e0c80bbdf4fdbca132ff80033b3f3/packages/showdown/package.js#L7).

Comment: I assumed `api.export` always exported to the full project! Actually, it's used to export objects which can then be imported in multiple ways: To the whole project (`meteor add`), to the scope of a package (`api.use`) or both (`api.imply`). Thanks for the insights!

Comment: This concept is basically the same as re-exporting in NPM packages, for example, in ES6: `export {Foo} from 'other-package'` or in CommonJS: `exports.Foo = require('other-package').Foo`. Meteor 1.3 supports NPM modules out-of-the-box now, just `npm install` in your app's root directory, then `require()` or `import` whatever you need in your app code (or write packages that re-export things, and optionally publish them on NPM instead of Atmosphere).

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding this but I don't really understand the difference between meteor add'ing a package, which makes it explicitly listed/defined, and api.imply'ing it.It seems like they essentially do the same thing, but that api.imply means now you potentially have a bunch of packages available that are hard to find/maintain because they're littered throughout an assortment of package definitions. Am I right about that, and if so, what's the strength in it over meteor add?

Answer (score 0):

If you have something in your app that consumes api from `package:name` and you install just package `package:dependant` which has a `package:name` as a dependency, but you don't use `imply` here, your api from `package:name` will not work in the app. It will work only in `package:dependant` package. You need use `imply` if you want to use something from `package:name` outside your `package:dependant`

I don't know if this is clear ;)

Comment: I still don't get it. I have to use `imply` to have the API of the first package working in the whole app? And if I use `imply` it will export this API everywhere?

Comment: It will install `package:name` and you will be able to use it everywhere in the app. Just like it is when you run `meteor add package:name`