# Meteor package: Templates not found

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to write a package with its own templates. In my `package.js` I am doing

```
api.imply([
    'meteor-platform',
    ...
]);

api.addFiles([
    'client/templates/brain_layout.html',
    ...
], 'client');
api.addFiles([
    'client/templates/brain_layout.js',
    ...
], 'client');
```

In my `brain_layout.html` I am doing

```
<template name="brainLayout">
    <div id="wrap">
    ...
    </div>
    {{> footer}}
</template>
```

and in my `brain_layout.js` I am doing

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        console.log(Template);
        console.log(Template.brainLayout);
        Template.brainLayout.events({
        ...
        });
    });
}
```

The result is that I get an error by iron router saying `Couldn't find a template named "brainLayout" or "brainLayout". Are you sure you defined it?` and in the console I get `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Template.brainLayout.events')` as well as the output of my `console.log` lines. Those yield: a correctly defined `Template` constructor function and an **undefined** `Template.brainLayout`.

I have looked through several guides and stack overflow discussions but can't find the cause. Any ideas?

Comment: Get events() off the Meteor.startup clause. startup and events are different thing

Comment: sorry but that is a nonsense reply: first of all it is about `brainLayout` not being found not `brainLayout.events`. Second, outside `Meteor.startup` not even the `Template` global object is defined.

Comment: Sooo, you define your events/helpers in Meteor.startup? How is Template not visible from outside of Meteor.startup?

Comment: Sindis I have to apologise for my 2nd remark: you are right that one can also put `Template` outside of `startup`, sorry! The observation that it was not defined outside `startup` was an artefact of the actual cause for the overall problem: `templating` not being included with `use`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to `api.use('templating', 'client');` in your `package.js`. Without that dependency, package templates won't be recognized.

Also note that you don't need the `if (Meteor.isClient)` check in `brain_layout.js` if that file is only added to the client.

Comment: I had tried it without `Meteor.isClient` first (no luck), the cause was the missing `api.use('templating', 'client');` - so `imply` is _only_ making the stuff available for users of the package but not the package itself? That seems nonsensical to me, but anyways.. thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah the docs for `api.imply` are super confusing. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928376/what-does-api-imply-do) for more details.