# Adding package dependencies without using `meteor add`

Tags: meteor

In meteor, is there a way to include a sub-package (package from within another package) without typing `meteor add package-name` at the command prompt each time?

At the moment I have `iron:router` declared as a package dependency for one of my packages, but in order to get it working I need to run `meteor add iron:router` at the command line, even if I have included it in my `package.js` file with `api.use(...)`.

This is not a problem for 1 project and/or 1 package but I am trying to create a 'boiler-plate' package that includes several sub-packages such that I only have to include 1 package for any new project & all the dependencies are automatically loaded as well.

E.g. Given that `packages/boilerplate/package.js` would have the following declaration...

```
api.use([
  'iron:router@1.0.9',
  'my:package-A@x.x.x',
  'my:package-B@x.x.x',
  'my:package-C@x.x.x',
  'my:package-D@x.x.x',
  'my:package-E@x.x.x',
  'my:package-F@x.x.x',
]);
```

...I still have to run `meteor add` for each of those for every project, which largely defeats the point of doing this.

I am developing on Windows 8.1 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Well, I asked a similar question which I think will solve your issue perfectly. It's not a duplicate, but it's very close: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928376/what-does-api-imply-do. You ask for the solution to an issue when I asked what issue the solution solved!

Comment: @Kyll Who would have thought it would be so easy!? RTFM! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `api.imply`, it will make these packages exported symbols available to your app without having to `meteor add` them separately.

```
var packages = [
  'iron:router@1.0.9',
  'my:package-A@x.x.x',
  'my:package-B@x.x.x',
  'my:package-C@x.x.x',
  'my:package-D@x.x.x',
  'my:package-E@x.x.x',
  'my:package-F@x.x.x',
];
// grant this package access to other packages symbols
api.use(packages);
// grant the app using this package access to other packages symbols
api.imply(packages);
```

Comment: Further info... I was using a sub-sub-package as the boilerplate so I had to redeclare the same `api.imply(...)` in both packages for it to finally propagate through to the app's files. So the imply only propagates to it's immediate parent which is either the app or another package.