# How to access a package variable from somewhere else in the application?

Tags: meteor

I have developed two Meteor packages that I have added into my Meteor application.
Each package has a log collection that I am trying to query from the Meteor Application. However, it seems I am unable to access those collections from the main application:

```
// pkg_1_log is defined in pkg_1 package.
pkg_1_log.find().count();
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: pkg_1_log

// pkg_2_log is defined in pkg_2 package.
pkg_2_log.find().count();
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: pkg_2_log
```

What do I need to tweak in order for that to work?

Comment: @Kyll : that was the fix! You are welcome to add your answer or I can add mine. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To provide access to a package-scoped variable (defined without `var`), you need to [export](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_export) it:

```
api.export('myVar');
```

You can specify the target architecture in the second argument.

You may then [`meteor add`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteoradd) your package to get this exported variable to the whole application but also [`api.use`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_use) it in another package or even [`api.imply`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_api_imply) it. If you are unsure as to what the difference between "using" and "implying" is then you should check [saimeunt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29928898/4174897).