# Why does using Mongo in package tests fail when the package has api.use('mongo')?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-velocity, meteor-packages

I'm developing a custom package. Its `package.js` is :

```
Package.describe({
  name: 'adigiovanni:one-way-accounts',
  version: '0.0.1',
  summary: 'One Way Accounts',
  git: '',
  documentation: 'README.md',
});

Package.onUse(function (api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.2.0.2');
  api.use('ecmascript');
  api.use('mongo');
  // api.imply('mongo');
  api.addFiles([
    'lib/collections/Accounts.js',
    'lib/methods.js',
    'lib/OneWayAccounts.js',
  ]);
  api.export('OneWayAccounts');
});

Package.onTest(function (api) {
  api.use([
    'ecmascript',
    'sanjo:jasmine@0.20.2',
    'velocity:html-reporter',
  ]);
  api.use('adigiovanni:one-way-accounts');
  api.addFiles('tests/client/OneWayAccounts.js', 'client');
  api.addFiles('tests/server/OneWayAccounts.js', 'server');
});
```

As you can see, package makes use of `'mongo'`.

Tests fail with :

> Reference error: Mongo is not defined

But if I uncomment the line `api.imply('mongo')` then tests succeed.

Same odd behavior applies to `ecmascript` dependency, if I don't  `api.use('ecmascript')` in `Package.onTest`, tests fail.

Meteor version is 1.2.0.2.
Test runner is velocity.
Test framework is jasmine.
I am using `Mongo` and ES6 syntax and features in my tests.

What is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: I can post an answer but I need one last information: Do you use `Mongo` in your test codes?

Comment: Yes. In lib/collections/Accounts.js. `Accounts = new Mongo.Collection('owa-accounts');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a package with [`api.use('other-package')`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_use) in `Package.onUse` does not make `'other-package'` available in your test codes in the same way it doesn't make it available for other packages that `use('my-package')` or in applications that `meteor add my-package`. To solve this issue there is two solutions depending on the need for `other-package` :

1. Allowing users of the package (including your tests) to access `'other-package'` with [`api.imply`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_api_imply)

   ```
   Package.onUse(function (api) {
     //...
     api.imply('other-package')
     //...
   })
   ```

   This makes sense if and only if the package you `imply` is **necessary to use your own package**. Do not `imply` everything willy-nilly for scope convenience. See more [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29928376/what-does-api-imply-do).
   If it does not fall into that category,
2. Simply `use` the package in your tests

   ```
   Package.onTest(function (api) {
     //...
     api.use('my-package')
     api.use('other-package')
     //...
   })
   ```

   This will allow you to use `other-package` in your tests too, without polluting scopes.

Comment: `package.js` boilerplate from Meteor version 1.2.0.2 has `api.use('ecmascript')` in `Package.onUse` and `Package.onTest`. So, I think you're right. Nonetheless my question is this: why tests need my package's dependencies to be listed explicitly if I do not use those dependencies in test code? I mean, Mongo is used internally by my package but I do not use Mongo in the tests. If I'd use my package in an app I wouldn't `meteor add mongo` in order to have my package work. Isn't it the same thing? I don't know if this is clear :)

Comment: Oh, from your answer to my comment I thought you used Mongo in your tests too. That is indeed pretty weird, I have noticed myself some similar weirdness with package testing on Meteor 1.2. I'll do some more tests and come back to you.